# WSL 環境の Ubuntu で作成したユーザー名・パスワードを忘れてしまった

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

あらかじめ了承いただきたいことがあります。
私はPC、プログラミングの学習を始めたてで、ITに関してはおそらく赤子同然です。
稚拙な文章、稚拙な知識ですが問題を解決したいと考えています。
もしこれが目に留まり、言ってることも解決方法もわかるよ！という奇特な方はどうかお助けいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いたします。

Windows10
WSL
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Windows10でUbuntuをダウンロードしVscodeなどで仮想環境構築に使用しようと考えていたのですが、Ubuntuを久しぶりに使用しようとしたところパスワードを忘れてしまい使用できませんでした。

- 再起動画面でESCキー、shiftキーを押してルートシェルにてパスワードを再設定する方法
  →ESCキー、shiftキーを押しても画面が変わらない
  上記の解決策を試したり、他に思い当たる解決策を調べてみましたが、解決できませんでした。
- コマンドプロンプトからUbuntu を開き、rootユーザーになって強制的にパスワードを変更する
  こちらの方法ではパスワードを使用せずにおそらくパスワードの変更ができそうでしたが、実施するにはユーザー名が必要で、ユーザー名も忘れるというあほさを発揮してしまい解決しませんでした。

もし上記以外で思い当たる解決策があれば教えていただきたいです。
解決策はわかりませんがあなたの知識はずれてる、まちがってますよという指摘をいただけるだけでも有難いです。宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺の記事を参考にUbuntuを初期化(リセット)すれば良いのでは？ [WSL2のUbuntuを初期化する](https://zenn.dev/kawacdev/articles/3de7892fd13df3), [WSL2のUbuntuのリセットとアンインストールする手順](https://blog.janjan.net/2021/03/08/windows10-wsl-save-ubuntu-reset-or-uninstall/) その前に何かしたいなら、ユーザー名はこちらで確認出来るでしょう。 [Ubuntu でユーザー一覧や現在のユーザを確認する方法](https://blog.totsugeki.com/post-1145/)

Comment: cubickさん、kunifさん、回答いただきありがとうございました。解決できました！Ubuntuをリセットし、windowsをupdateし、wslのインストール・wsl2カーネルの更新・wsl2を既定のバージョンとして設定、ubuntuは既にインストールしてあるので再度アカウントの登録をして、問題は解決しました。初めてここで質問をさせていただいたのですが、丁寧に適切な解決方法を教えていただけて本当に助かりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

#### ログインユーザーの (一時的な) 変更

コマンドプロンプトを開き、デフォルトユーザーを root に変更します。

```
> ubuntu config --default-user root
```

上記の設定変更後、Ubuntu のウィンドウを開き root ユーザーでログイン出来ているかを確認してください。

#### ユーザー名の確認

Ubuntu (Linux) では `/etc/passwd` にアカウント情報が記録されているので、この中身を確認して心当たりのあるユーザー名をチェックしてください。

```
> cat /etc/passwd
```

ユーザー名が確認できたら、`passwd` コマンドで新しいパスワードを設定します。
passwd コマンドに続けて変更したいユーザー名を指定します。

```
# passwd USER
```

パスワードの設定ができたら、コマンドプロンプトでデフォルトユーザーを元に戻しておきます。

```
> ubuntu config --default-user USER
```

**参考:**
[WSLでLinuxのパスワードを忘れてしまった場合の対処法](https://linuxfan.info/wsl-password-reset)